# Spark 2.0 + Kryo Serializer + Avro -> NullPointerException?

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

I have the simple pyspark program:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark_settings = {
        "spark.serializer": 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer'
    }

    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAll(spark_settings.items())
    spark_context = SparkContext(appName="test app", conf=conf)
    spark_sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)

    source_path = "s3n://my_bucket/data.avro"
    data_frame = spark_sql_context.read.load(source_path, format="com.databricks.spark.avro")
    # The schema comes back correctly.
    data_frame.printSchema()
    # This count() call fails. A call to head() triggers the same error.
    data_frame.count()
```

I run with

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master yarn \
  --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.0 \
    bug_isolation.py
```

It fails with the following exception and stack trace.

If I switch to `--master local` it works. If I disable the KryoSerializer option, it works. Or if I use a Parquet source rather than an Avro source it works.

The combination of using `--master yarn` and the KryoSerializer and an Avro source triggers the exception and stack trace listed below.

I suspect I may need to manually register some Avro plugin classes with the KryoSerializer for it to work? Which classes would I need to register.

```
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, ip-172-31-97-24.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:151)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I get the same error if I call `data_frame.head()`. Clearly, the data isn't empty, because it works perfectly without Kryo serialization _or_ if I run in local mode.

Comment: May I ask why you use Kryo? If it's really Spark 2.0, you should use SparkSession (not SparkContext and SQLContext), although it does not matter much for the case.

Comment: We use Kryo for speed. The official Spark docs recommend it. I know about SparkSession in 2.0, but my team is supposed to write 1.6 compatible code for the moment even though I'm using Spark 2.0 at runtime.